# Question about a pointer in a program. [C]

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the full code of it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(unsigned short *buf, int length)
{
    int i;
    unsigned short temp;

    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = buf[i];
        buf[i] = buf[length - i - 1];
        buf[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned short* tmp = (unsigned short*)argv[1];
    reverse_string(tmp,strlen(argv[1]) / 2);

    printf("%s",argv[1]);

    return 0;   
}
```

As you can see, in main, we have

```
unsigned short* tmp = (unsigned short*)argv[1];
```

Arent pointers supposed to point "to the address of" of a variable? The one above isn't(using the ampersand). Yet the program works as intended.

Why is it like that?

And what does this part mean?

```
(unsigned short*)argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the original questions:

`argv` is an array of pointers, each of which point to a character array.  `argv[1]` is a pointer to the character array with the first argument (i.e. if you run `./program arg1 arg2`, the pointer `argv[1]` points to the string `arg1`).

The ampersand is used to denote a reference, which is for most purposes the same as a pointer.  It is syntactic sugar to make it easy to pass a reference to a variable that you have already declared.  The common example is using scanf.

```
int x = 1;
scanf(..., &x, ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
int x = 1;
int *p = &x;
scanf(..., p, ...)
```

The program itself is designed to flip endianness.  It's not sufficient to go character-by-character because you have to flip two bytes at a time (ie short-by-short), which is why it works using shorts.

`(unsigned short*)argv[1]` instructs the compiler to treat the address as if it were an array of shorts.  To give an example:

```
unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
c[1]; /*this points to the address one byte after argv*/
unsigned short *s = (unsigned short *)argv[1];
s[1]; /*this points to the address two bytes after argv */
```

Answer (score 6):

`argv` is a pointer-to-an-array-of-pointers:

- `argv[0][0]`  (a `char`)
- `argv[0]`     (a `char*`)
- `argv`        (a `char**`)

  `unsigned char* tmp = (unsigned char*)argv[1];`

...works, because you're referencing the the second "string" in that set.

Note that in this case, "`char`" and "`unsigned short`" *might be* roughly equivolent depending on the compiler and platform, but it is probably not a good idea to assume that.  For example, if you compiled to enable a "unicode" command line, then you might get "`short`" instead of "`char`" forwarded to you from the command line.  But, that may be a dangerous assumption, as "these days" a "`short`" is usually 16-bits and a "`char`" is usually 8-bits.

Comment: isn't a short often twice the size of a char? That would also make sense with them taking `strlen / 2`.

Comment: @sharth, good point, I updated to clarify when it might/might-not be a good idea...

Comment: `char` and `unsigned short` are not "roughly equivalent". On most platforms a char is a single byte while a short is 2 bytes. The OP's program doesn't do a very good job of reversing the input string because of that strange cast to `unsigned short *` and the fact that his reversal function want an `unsigned short *` instead of a `char *`. http://www.ideone.com/2aZPr

Comment: @Praetorian, I agree, I updated with a stronger warning. (I remember the days when a `short` was a `char`, and you're right, that's a really bad assumption anymore.) (We do embedded hardware, and `char` is still often `short` for our compilers.)

Comment: Actually, it does a very good job at reversing it. It's job is not just to "reverse it" it's to swap the endiannes of the string

Comment: @dikidera except it doesn't work for a string with an odd number of characters. The last character is left in place while the rest of the string is swapped around.

Comment: @Praetorian: the character left out of the the loop is the one in the middle, which doesn't need to be swapped. e.g. ABCDE -> EDCBA; C can remain where it is, and only 2 (= 5 / 2) swaps required.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: That seems to be the intent, but look at the call to `reverse_string()`. Because of `strlen(argv[1]) / 2` as the second input parameter to the function it'll never be called with an odd string length. So the last character does remain in place. Take a look at the link I posted in an earlier comment.

Comment: @sharth: no, that has nothing to do with the length / 2. Length / 2 is the number of required swaps. Apparently, on the platform this code was written, unsigned short is the size of a char. But even if that is the case, it should use char and not unsigned short, IMO.

Comment: @Praetorian: Ok, I see what you mean. ISTM that the algorithm is correct, but the function call with strlen(argv[0]) / 2 is wrong. And of course the use of unsigned short instead of char.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a primer on [type casting](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson11.html).

Comment: argc and argv define the number of parameters and the values of the parameters in the program command.  Here the second element of argv (a char pointer) is being cast to a unsigned short pointer.